# Does the Ruby VM define the file format that runs on it?

Tags: ruby, virtual-machine

Like the ".class" file that runs on JVM, does the Ruby VM(MRI, or YARV) define the file format that rns on it?
I have read in some articles that YARV bytecode was considered a internal format, which means that there are little documentations or specifications about it, is it true?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tl;dr No, ruby does not define a runable format other than the language itself.

It is true that ruby doesn't have a standard bytecode format like java, etherium, and others. Every ruby implementation JRuby, MRI Ruby, TruffleRuby, etc. gets to decide how exactly they run ruby code.

Ruby implementations *can* choose to implement their own bytecode format. Those formats would likely be private to that ruby implementation and unlikely to be seen outside of that eco-system. (however as we've seen with languages popping up that [run on the JVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_JVM_languages) it's possible for other people to piggy back off your language's VM if they'd like)

It's completely valid for a ruby implementation to run inside the JVM run on java byte code JVM [jruby](https://www.jruby.org/), to introduce a compilation step to produce native machine code [ruby-llvm](https://github.com/ruby-llvm/ruby-llvm), or even to sometimes produce native machine code at runtime with a JIT and sometimes use a more traditional interpreter [MRI Ruby](https://github.com/ruby/ruby).